# Gnuplot: results differ when exporting to pdf and when plotting with qt

Tags: pdf, gnuplot

I am trying to plot a figure including the average of a distribution and its standard deviation using `filledcurves` with `gnuplot`. I get my figure by setting my `terminal` to `pdf`. However, when the points of my distribution do not belong to the displayed range of my y-axis, I noticed that the slope of my curve was wrong. This is even more surprising that I do get the right results when plotting my results first with qt and then exporting manually my figure to `pdf`.

Here is my minimal working example:

```
reset session

set terminal pdf
set output "~/MWE_results.pdf"

set yr[-100 : 100]

$Data <<EOD
40   0.000011           -0.002104            0.002126
20   0.240582           -4.877879            5.359043
10   0.926508           -9.378468           11.231484
5    4.794549          -19.298995           28.888093
2.5  84.993925        -6679.709571         6849.697422
1.25 6.220374        -3980.189531         3992.630280
EOD

set style fill transparent solid 0.1 

plot $Data u 1:2 w lp pt 7 lc rgb "black" ti "Mean value of my distribution", \
     $Data u 1:3:4 w filledcurves lc rgb "red" ti "Std devation"

unset output

unset term
```

This code gives me the following results (I circled the problematic slope):
[image: results I get when exporting directly to pdf]

While the pdf file I get when plotting my results with qt and then exporting to pdf is the following (and is consistent with my data):

[image: results I get when exporting directly when plotting with qt and then exporting to pdf]

Does anyone have any idea what might be happening?

Thank you in advance for the help

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I cannot reproduce with gnuplot 5.2.8 and 5.4.0, but I can reproduce with 5.4.5. and 5.5.0, but like you only with `terminal pdf`. Which version of gnuplot are you running.? I would assume that this might be a newly introduced bug when connecting/clipping data outside of the graph. Maybe there is a  workaround. Otherwise use gnuplot<=5.4.0

Comment: An other observation: you won't see this behaviour in 5.4.5 if you `set yrange[-100:347.2]`, but if the upper y-border is <347 you will see this effect. Pretty strange. I think something is miscalculated.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I am using gnuplot 5.4.5, and the problem doesn't exist when I use gnuplot 5.2.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, this is a really strange behaviour. I would say this is a `terminal pdfcairo`-specific bug.

In your special case, the upper and lower borders for fill are always above and below y=0, respectively.
So, a workaround which works in your case and in gnuplot 5.4.5 and 5.5.0 and with `term pdfcairo` is the following: separately fill your upper and lower border to y=0. The result will be like your second (expected) graph. Maybe there are better workarounds.

```
plot $Data u 1:2 w lp pt 7 lc rgb "black" ti "Mean value of my distribution", \
     $Data u 1:3 w filledcurves y=0 lc rgb "red" ti "Std devation", \
     $Data u 1:4 w filledcurves y=0 lc rgb "red" notitle
```

Comment: Thank you, the workaround works perfectly in my case! Using a version <=5.4.0 also seems to work very well.

Comment: @Alice, glad to hear. If the answer solved your problem, please check the checkmark at the top left of the answer indicating that the question is answered. If there might be coming a better answer you can always unaccept and accept another answer.